# PHP mp3 download script doesn't work on Android phones

Tags: php, android

I have a PHP script which I use to server mp3 files from my website. It works well on desktop browsers but fails to work on Android browsers. I keep getting a "Download Unsuccessful" error on Android phones when I try to download an mp3 file from my website.
This is the code:

```
session_start();
$post_id = $_SESSION['post_id'];

$_SESSION['post_id'] = '';

require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/wp-blog-header.php" );



function set_download_count($postID) {
    $count_key = 'custom_download_count';
    $dcount = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($dcount==''){
        $dcount = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $dcount++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $dcount);
    }
}

$count = $_GET['count'];
//$post_id = $_GET['p'];
$count++;

$file = $_GET['file']; 

//$output = array_shift(explode('&', $file));

if($count == 1) {
    //echo "1";
    set_download_count($post_id);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file)."");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

readfile($file);
exit;


}else {
     echo "0";
    exit();
}
```

Does anyone know what's causing this and how it can be resolved? Thanks.

Comment: try to comment ob_clean(); flush(); you don't need to create a buffer.

Comment: @volkinc, I have commented out ob_clean(); and flush(); but it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: There is no Download unsuccessfull error in your code visible. Your code moreover is only a very small piece. What can we see on it? And you did not show your php script.

Comment: @greenapps, I have edited the question and added the entire script. The "Download Unsuccessful" error occurs on the Android phones.

Comment: You forgot  to post the Andoid code. Do you think its not needed?

Comment: @greenapps, the code I posted is for the website. There is no Android code because what I'm working on is just a website.

Comment: `when I try to download an mp3 file from my website.`. Then please explain exactly what you are doing to invoke this. And tell which of the many browsers for Android you tested.

Comment: I think you miss an empty line after the headers.